# jquery selector after addClass

Tags: jquery

Why this doesn't work:

```js
$('.parent').clone().addClass('lorem');

$('.lorem').insertBefore('.parent');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: `.clone()` returns a new element that isn’t in the document. `$('selector')` doesn’t select things that aren’t in the document.

Comment: @Ry-, the new element is maybe in the cosmic space. Where is it?. How it can be selected using new class?

Comment: It’s nowhere if you don’t put the return value somewhere (e.g. in a variable).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($('.parent'))
$('div.parent').clone().appendTo("body").addClass('lorem');

$('.lorem').insertBefore('.parent');
})
```

Comment: It is unnecessary you are putting an element to body first then inserting it. In this way it will have more than two elements in the DOM which is incorrect.

Comment: @Manoz, I checked by counting elements (`.length`) before and after `clone` and `insert`. There is no two elements in the DOM !?

Answer (score 3):

You are targeting element which is not in DOM yet.

You can try

```
var cloneElement = $('.parent').clone().addClass('lorem');

cloneElement.insertBefore('.parent');
```

You might need to insert cloned element in the DOM in order to select it.

Now if you log the `.lorem` element, You will be able to find it.

You can verify -

```
console.log($('.lorem').length) //returns 1 element
```